# WooCommerce add_action hook results in 500 error

Tags: functions, hooks, actions

I am trying to add a line of text on the checkout page of the store that will go immediately after shipping row. I added the following to my child theme functions.php file:

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'action_woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping');

function action_woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping( ) {
    echo = "<p>Text Goes Here</p>";
};
```

For some reason it leads to a 500 error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `=` sign after your `echo` statement...

`echo = "<p>Text Goes Here</p>";`

...becomes

`echo "<p>Text Goes Here</p>";`

Final

```
 add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping', 'action_woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping');

function action_woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping( ) {
    echo "<p>Text Goes Here</p>";
}
```

Comment: wow...I have been looking at this for way too long. thanks!

Comment: No problem :) ...don't forget to mark the question correct to close it out. All the best.